# How to make flotchart cross axis

Tags: javascript, flot

I can't find an example of making axis to cross at (0,0)
All examples on flotcharts.org use rectangular axes.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want both the x-axis and y-axis to start with 0?

Comment: Yes. When axis cross at (0,0)

Comment: Like this?: http://jsfiddle.net/Margo/yKG7X/6/

Comment: Was that what you were looking for?

Comment: No. Axis don't cross. What if x and y limits don't start form 0?

Comment: aaah i know what you mean now. Sorry, don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [Matt Burland's Origin Axis](https://github.com/burlandm/Flot-Origin-Axis) plugin.